# How iOS Framework loads resources from outside

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

I am developing a cocoa touch framework.

When you embed this framework to your project it will displays your app icon to an WKWebView (html)

I know how to pass data from swift to javascript using WebKit evaluateJavascript, but how I can access the app icon of a project from my framework and display it in an web view (html)?

If the html file was inside the project folder and not in a framework I would load the app icon simply by saying in the html

```
<img src="appiconname.png">
```

because they are in the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the swift 3.0 solution in case someone has the same issue.

Reference to the main bundle (either inside a framework the main bundle refers to the main of the running application) to retrieve the relative path:

```
let appIconPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Icon", ofType: "png")!
```

Then pass it to html tag using

```
webView.evaluateJavascript(...)
```